# All emails from all domains going to Gmails Spam folder (ip is not in the spam list and SPF/DKIM/DMARC passes)

Tags: gmail

everything was all-right, but since 2018-10th month all emails from all my domains have started to go to Gmail Spam box. I've checked my domain ip, it is normal, no spam  - detected and not in the Spam list.

SPF/DKIM/DMARC successfully passed.

Mail tester website also shows scores: 10/10.  https://www.mail-tester.com/test-tzzus.

Seems that Google something has added to their headers, but what?
What My emails are missing?

Here is my email full header:

```
Message ID  <001901d46c37$4d1993f0$e74cbbd0$@stockus.eu>
Created:    2018 m. spalio 25 d. 10:49 (delivered after 8 seconds)
From:   justin@stockus.eu Is sent using: „Microsoft Outlook 16.0“
To: whopaintedstars@gmail.com
Subject:    test
SPF:    PASS with IP 212.24.106.206 (sužinokite daugiau)
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain stockus.eu. Learn more
DMARC:  'PASS' Learn more

   Delivered-To: whopaintedstars@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a50:f618:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id c24-v6csp124076edn;
        Thu, 25 Oct 2018 00:49:48 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AJdET5dvwP/0NtXyW1OTKlRfqbTxlD7HbwUo6cJT6paa2PImyFaoNbWJ6rQYZKxHfctdGmvl/5+S
X-Received: by 2002:adf:b612:: with SMTP id f18-v6mr644955wre.120.1540453788086;
        Thu, 25 Oct 2018 00:49:48 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1540453788; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=QvFh8JufshfPYjwpyU6LI94dDiyNlL9eGomNEx67bFMc/zeyRtVeiJzrYt0fi1Y533
         lhksy9xHmkBJ+qHImZZgobFvN35p7tm+o9m8SvMCqKWsvuZ5Ec5CAjZtbjq98UXHboFk
         dT+f8WgmVd3vzAD1UbWZllAjZhXWyOKCdj2kyHxhb2F5KZCeoni9psCZ3mZHL+opM2Kn
         xZ5/vV8EWnVP5QBYkbFz0itNnlRHLm3uy3F1+kUAo6zh4XaeZtSMe0CPaza92lNev+It
         q3ORlboaDsDXSYPDQi1w/s9GMeGnIzbi4OCZb0/3ezRSz58pDqLDCNOM8fWJzry+edll
         I+Cw==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-language:thread-index:mime-version:message-id:date:subject
         :to:from:dkim-signature;
        bh=w0aP52/Y1KgFFoyCMiFCDmy55cW4afgt+I0jLJNlHbw=;
        b=g2UlOcJSHhGbOCn4zgy2eLOmkHwza34KAzUkq5WbC3tv7h/g4Ja7cdRfPK2FXeeDBB
         20hPzqkBR/qSG4TM4SB0xsrqvizQLsOo0zyyxk7mS9KqusDrDMBZ7FhpSggJyFuoyk6O
         jPmqzUY9ZkBZTbL0K9Jz4yousUjJKqE9sb014/WahirwE/LPmtlvtLppT7Z5yjeTVDz5
         s1RXWvXFo0HohTX7qwryL5T+xxQacgWHcw6wI/VzyB/+uKpiiuPP4s9EAR9W3vy1d/ws
         lXmDz7MHMdcgN/9jcTUCONVdEc1vrO6oHkUKPdygFmbwEAL0mFJs9l7AOi8+tyhpMAMy
         F0Sg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@stockus.eu header.s=x header.b="tz72j/Us";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of justin@stockus.eu designates 212.24.106.206 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=justin@stockus.eu;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=stockus.eu
Return-Path: <justin@stockus.eu>
Received: from server.allunitedartists.com (server.allunitedartists.com. [212.24.106.206])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e4-v6si6841273wrc.55.2018.10.25.00.49.47
        for <whopaintedstars@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 25 Oct 2018 00:49:47 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of justin@stockus.eu designates 212.24.106.206 as permitted sender) client-ip=212.24.106.206;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@stockus.eu header.s=x header.b="tz72j/Us";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of justin@stockus.eu designates 212.24.106.206 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=justin@stockus.eu;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=stockus.eu
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=stockus.eu;
     s=x; h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Date:Subject:To:From:Sender: Reply-To:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description: Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID: In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe: List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=w0aP52/Y1KgFFoyCMiFCDmy55cW4afgt+I0jLJNlHbw=; b=tz72j/Us5kjAovnSiiCnLniHkc pLuZfL4ZhT/TNKwKy6HNmCqV4CP4KXIqfzS3K0jmXKt/iKh6708OtoaFDRGR/M0gXJwBONvenCkyk xBipVm3Tf6M3DKM8Te97mPtwvvPm3lcOndX/yGKUFJUSZaa83zsuWHO/5N9KzBuQUPBjI0X0WA3M2 g76A5wZr5MMCC0hiYgzXuRcfUkEfEYsyEGqHQsFNWvNtVz7QklGyprGpFJi9m3JFmiBtHE7dhB/eX dAiLoflxubX+H/gS9n0Bo8Ki+V9Z7/mUSMfLQ4AoaChoG3yYpXfRTbecbi8g4lC1iVe/CQplOULaO nuo02+2A==;
Received: from [212.122.80.79] (helo=DESKTOP7V86M8L) by server.allunitedartists.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.91) (envelope-from <justin@stockus.eu>) id 1gFaOp-0004FC-5r for whopaintedstars@gmail.com; Thu, 25 Oct 2018 10:49:47 +0300
From: <justin@stockus.eu>
To: <whopaintedstars@gmail.com>
Subject: test
Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 10:49:39 +0300
Message-ID: <001901d46c37$4d1993f0$e74cbbd0$@stockus.eu>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_001A_01D46C50.72674120"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 16.0
Thread-Index: AdRsN0QalLjFurG3Q4qf3AyZZypMwQ==
Content-Language: lt
X-Authenticated-Id: justin@stockus.eu

------=_NextPart_000_001A_01D46C50.72674120
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test



--

Justin Stockus

Mob: +37061211114

Email: justin@stockus.eu <mailto:justin@stockus.eu> 

Web: www.stockus.eu




------=_NextPart_000_001A_01D46C50.72674120
Content-Type: text/html; charset="US-ASCII"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-micr=
osoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" =
xmlns:m=3D"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns=3D"http:=
//www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV=3D"Content-Type" CONTENT=
=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"><meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Micros=
oft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
=09{font-family:"Cambria Math";
=09panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
=09{font-family:Calibri;
=09panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
=09{margin:0cm;
=09margin-bottom:.0001pt;
=09font-size:11.0pt;
=09font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
=09mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
=09{mso-style-priority:99;
=09color:#0563C1;
=09text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
=09{mso-style-priority:99;
=09color:#954F72;
=09text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
=09{mso-style-type:personal-compose;
=09font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
=09color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
=09{mso-style-type:export-only;
=09font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
=09mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
=09{size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
=09margin:3.0cm 1.0cm 2.0cm 3.0cm;}
div.WordSection1
=09{page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext=3D"edit" spidmax=3D"1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext=3D"edit">
<o:idmap v:ext=3D"edit" data=3D"1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=3DLT link=3D"#0563C1" v=
link=3D"#954F72"><div class=3DWordSection1><p class=3DMsoNormal><span lang=
=3DEN-US>test<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=3DMsoNormal><span lang=3DEN-US>=
<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=3DMsoNormal><span lang=3DEN-US style=
=3D'mso-fareast-language:LT'>--<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=3DMsoNormal><=
span lang=3DEN-US style=3D'mso-fareast-language:LT'>Justin Stockus<o:p></o:=
p></span></p><p class=3DMsoNormal><span lang=3DEN-US style=3D'mso-fareast-l=
anguage:LT'>Mob: </span><span lang=3DEN-US style=3D'font-family:"Arial",san=
s-serif;mso-fareast-language:LT'>+</span><span lang=3DEN-US style=3D'mso-fa=
reast-language:LT'>37061211114</span><span lang=3DEN-US style=3D'mso-fareas=
t-language:LT'><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=3DMsoNormal><span lang=3DEN-U=
S style=3D'mso-fareast-language:LT'>Email: <a href=3D"mailto:justin@stockus=
.eu">justin@stockus.eu</a><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=3DMsoNormal><span =
lang=3DEN-US style=3D'mso-fareast-language:LT'>Web: www.stockus.eu<o:p></o:=
p></span></p><p class=3DMsoNormal><span lang=3DEN-US><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></spa=
n></p></div></body></html>
------=_NextPart_000_001A_01D46C50.72674120--
```

Thank You !!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right - mail-tester test looks very good! But you are testing for test message with very simplified content. Most likely your real mail send outs spam-classed by Google exactly due to mail HTML and/or text content. For example in your real mail exerpt the first thing I see i the subject 'test' which is itself provocative and even when you testing especially with real providers you should try to keep your test mail as real as possible starting even with subject line. Otherwise it can be something wrong or mismatching with subject, links and urls in body, words and phrases used, if html body matches text body well. These are enough reasons to decrease deliverability rating much enough. So please try to test one of real send outs mails which you mail to google and check mail-tester results again. Then you are welcome with more question! Regards!